# Cannot write with dir permission 666, but can write with 777

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

I am using Kali as root user. I did setup an atftp server in a folder (created and owned by root) and gave 666 permission on that folder. But I noticed users get permission denied error while uploading into atftp. Same was happening with FTP server. So to perform some tests, I created a temporary directory, assigned it 666 permission, tried to create a file using unpriviledged user and I got 'Permission denied'. Then I changed the permission to 777 and repeated the same process. This time file got created.

**Case 1: 666 permission**

```sh
root@kali:~/temp# chmod 666 .
root@kali:~/temp# ls -la
total 8
drw-rw-rw-  2 root root 4096 May  7 00:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root 4096 May  7 00:32 ..
root@kali:~/temp# su temp
$ touch a
touch: cannot touch 'a': Permission denied
```

**Case 2: 777 permission**

```sh
root@kali:~/temp# chmod 777 .
root@kali:~/temp# ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 May  7 00:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root 4096 May  7 00:32 ..
root@kali:~/temp# su temp
$ touch a
$ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 May  7 00:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root 4096 May  7 00:32 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 temp temp    0 May  7 00:32 a
$
```

How come adding additional `x` permission is helping with writing files even when folder had `w` in both cases?

Comment: Kali is not really suitable for general Linux use.

Comment: What do you really mean 'not suitable'? How do you decide one? And how does it matter in regards to the asked question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute bit on directories grant permission to enter into it, [see this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work)

> The execute bit (x) allows the affected user to enter the directory, and access files and directories inside

666 has no execute bit whereas 777 does.

Comment: Ah! Completely forgot there's a unix stackexchange too. Thanks for the clarification and links! :)